# Can we prove that if the sequence is not bounded, then for any $n\in \Bbb N $ we have $|x_n|\ge n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

From the definition of boundedness, it is obvious that unboundedness implies for all $N\in \Bbb N $ we have $|x_n|\ge N$.

But an analysis says that [image]

It seems that maybe there is a typo that for any $n\in \Bbb N $ we have $|x_n|\ge n$. But so far I cannot find an example that can disprove this statement, so I wonder if it is actually provable although that is not obvious.

Now may I please ask if it is true? If it is, may I please ask for a proof? Or if it is just a typo, could someone please show me a counterexample? Thanks.

Comment: its not "for any $n$". Its actually "$\exists \:n$".

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that sentence. It says the following: since $S$ is not bounded, for every natural number $n$ there exists an element, say $x$ such that $|x|\ge n$; now, simply label that element by $x_n$.

Comment: Well, $n$ is already being used for the dimension of the set, since it says $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.  So they should use some other index variable.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a typo. You just misunderstood the sentence.

For your question "if the sequence is not bounded then ... ", just consider $x_n=n-1$.

But the proof didn't assume that. It just said there *exists* a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $S$ such that $|x_n|\ge n$.

Answer (score 0):

It is true. Suppose $S$ is unbounded. Then for all $n\in \Bbb N$, there exists at least one element $x_n\in S$ such that $|x_n|\geq n$, since if no such element existed then $S$ would be bounded by $n$.